# Controlling Class Visibility in Java

Tags: java, api, usability, access-modifiers

My project has currently following package structure.

[image]

Here I have added a package name `utils` and defined all utility classes related to this module inside it. Those have been used by other packages (i.e. `impl`, `internal`), and because of that I have made classes and methods in `util` package `public`.

Because, it is public, not only classes in this module, classes in other modules can also access this and when I am coding using my IDE they are shown as coding suggestions.

I went through few research papers which describe how this can reduce the usability of the API and give a bad experience to developers who involve in the development [[ref1](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jeffrey_Stylos/publication/303507901_Improving_API_usability/links/577688b808ae1b18a7e1ac5f.pdf), [ref2]](https://www.cs.usask.ca/~croy/papers/2011/ZER_WCRE2011_APIUSability.pdf).

I understand that java does not allow me to make classes inside `util` accessible to `impl` and internal packages and not to others.

Is it correct to put my utility classes to a package 'util'? Or should I put all classes that communicate with each other to the same package?

Comment: In terms of OOP design you should not have an utility classes :)

Comment: Did I use a bad example ? o.O

Comment: Which IDE are you using? In Eclipse the first classes that are shown as code suggestions are the ones in the same package or in the imported classes (including `java.lang.*`). Other public classes do appear, but they are shown after those.

Comment: I'm using idea. Since these classes are not intended to use in other packages at all, I am trying to make them not accessible by other packages.
Since I am using OSGI to load my modules, if by accident someone will use this in a different class since it was suggested by IDE, it will result in runtime errors.

Comment: This may be overkill, but as the application grows it can be easier to manage the code base with multiple projects. For example, each functional layer of the app is in its own project. This can include the util classes in its own project, where the util.jar simply becomes a dependency by the other projects which need it.  This helps avoid util classes becoming junk drawers since a developer has to intentionally go to another project to add new util classes/methods.  Depending on the build tool, this will also force util classes to be generic to avoid circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, something marked **public** becomes usable in *any* other package. In contrast to other languages, Java doesn't provide any control beyond that.

A simple workaround: it might be helpful to have **one** special package containing those **public** things that should be available to your **external** users.

Meaning: create something like `com.whatever.product.api` - and instruct your users that they are fine to use everything from there - but nothing else.

In other words: you make all those things *public* that you need to *public*; but you collect those things in a special place that you allow to be used by others.

It is worth mentioning though that Java9 will introduce the concept of **[modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/)**, those allow you to define which of your packages should be **public** to **users** of your module. In that sense, java 9 modules allow you to distinguish between "internal" and "external" *public*.

Answer (score 1):

Util classes are fine. Util classes are functionality that is used multiple places in a project but doesn't really belong to a specific class.

In a perfect world of OOP there wouldn't be any util classes, but it is however considered a good practice to create util classes if they do not belong to a specific class.

Your options for access modifiers are listed here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

There is one way to achieve what you you want, it is however concidered a very bad practice. You can change your access modifiers of  util classes to `protected`. This will make your util classes accessible from subclasses and packages. So if a class needs access to one of the util classes, then it has to extend this util class and thereby become a subclass. **I cannot stress it enought, this is a very bad practice.**

Comment: So can I assume the package structure I have used is common and there is nothing wrong with it?

Comment: Your post does not contain enough details to determine your project structure, besides the package names. It is good practice to seperate a project into pacakges. You mentioned something about API? Are you trying to create an API?

Comment: Just remember that, if anyone want to use your utils classes, then they have to import that package otherwise it will not be visible for them. So it kinda takes care of itself as long as they do not import your util classes.

Comment: https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-workflow-impl-bps/tree/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/workflow/impl this is part of the project, we can put this jar into m2 and access it in other codes.Classes in the org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl package are the API. Different projects can access functionalities through them. Other classes in other packages (eg:dao) are not supposed to access by outside classes.

Comment: I took a quick look. It seems like your util classes are "real" util classes, they do not seem to be related to the remaining code. Good luck with your project!

Comment: plus one, as i like it when other people give more "beyond the question itself" answers ... and for actually checking out his source code ;-)